# Unit test case for a pure class method React/JEST/Enzyme

Tags: unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {

  /* Extracts file name and returns it */
  getFileName(file_name, id) {
   const display_file_name = file_name.split(id)[1];
   return display_file_name;
  }
}

...

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SomeComponent);
```

I have this above component which is connected to redux.
I want to write a unit test case to the method *getFileName*.
I have written like below:

```
test('should return file name extracted from the compound file name string', () => {
      const wrapper = (store) => {
        return mount(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <BrowserRouter >
                    <Route component={SomeComponent} />
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>
        );
      }
      const store = createMockStore();

      let compoundFileName = 'something_18ba56fd3_filename.csv';
      let expectedFileName = 'filename.csv';
      const id = '18ba56fd3';

      const instance = wrapper(store).dive().instance();
      const result = instance.getFileName(compoundFileName, id);

      expect(result).toEqual(expectedFileName);
    });
```

Getting `TypeError: wrapper(...).dive is not a function`

Please help.

Comment: As far as I know, `dive` is only available for Shallow Rendering, check https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html Are you sure you can't replace `mount` with `shallow` for your test?

Comment: I just want to know how to access that method in the class for testing. May it be shallow or mount.

Comment: If you just replace `mount` with `shallow` in your code, the error you get will be fixed

Comment: Neither of them is working for me.

Comment: If you use shallow, do you get the same error?